# MVC 4.5 ignores value in model if a matching field is in URL or post data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I saw some unexpected behavior this weekend.  I created a super simple page to demonstrate MVC to someone who was learning it.   It simply had two methods 'Index()' and '[HttpPost] Index(string text)'

model contained one item, 'string Text {get;set;}'

in Index()  -the get,  I created a model, and set the value of Text to "Enter some text" and returned View(model)

In the cshtml file, I had two items:

@Html.TextBoxFor (m=>m.Text)

and

@Model.Text

Which would just display the value of Text.

And a submit button.  (Submitted it back to Index)

Here is where it gets weird.   In the Post method, I simply created a new model, set the 'Text' property to whatever text was passed in + "!!"

I expected that if I set the text to 'a', and hit the button, it should redisplay 'a!!' in the text box as well as display 'a!!' below that.

However, instead, the value of the edit box remains the same, and the value of the @Model.Text changes!

This will also happen if you execute GET URL with text=A  - then no matter what you pass in your model, it will OVERRIDE the value used in the TextBoxFor/TextAreaFor and show 'A'!  But, the value from @Model.Text will be correctly displayed as the value in the model passed to the view.

It seems they had to go out of their way to break this - supporting getting data from the URL/Post Data instead of the model.

Wtf?

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestApp.Models;

namespace TestApp.Controllers
{
    public class homeController : Controller
    {

       public ActionResult Index()
       {
          TestModel model = new TestModel { Text = "Enter your text here! };
          return View(model);
       }
       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
       {
          model.Text = model.Text + "!!";
          return View(model);
       }

    }
}
```

View:

```
@using TestApp.Models
@model TestModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Text, 10,50,null)
<br />
<hr />
<br />

    @Model.Text
<br>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

And for completeness, the model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestApp.Models
{
   public class TestModel
   {
      public string Text { get; set; }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. Values from `Request` and/or `ViewData` (which includes `ViewBag`) are used to create the `ModelState` object, and values in `ModelState` override values in the model. This is necessary in order for posted values to override the actual model data.

Take for example the situation where a user posts a form, but has an error that prevents the data from being saved. The user is sent back to the form. Now what should happen here? Because the data was not saved, the model still has the original values from the database or whatever. If the model's values took precedence, then anything the user had previously entered would be overwritten. However, if the `ModelState` values are used, the user sees the form as they originally submitted it and can make any necessary modifications to submit again. Obviously the latter option is the ideal one.

Comment: Which would also make it impossible to have a form with a value that is updated when you submit the form (without it being a different form?)   Can you clear the ModelState?

Comment: You can use `ModelState.Clear()` (clear all) or `ModelState[YourPropertyName].Errors.Clear();` (clear one property), but you should be following the PRG pattern rather than doing this.

Comment: Good to know.  BTW: as a result of this, you can alter any web page using MVC to return different data by changing the URL.  In addition to whatever params you need to pass to the URL, you can add some-field=newValue to the command and then there will be no way (unless the person calls clear) for the programmer to send values back to the page -and I believe this will also bypass the verification that it came from that server as well.    In reference to the PRG pattern, I was doing this as a simple demo to show you could return back whatever form you wanted to - and I found out that wasn't true

Comment: It seems that this would enable Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery by allowing bypassing MVC’s AntiForgeryToken - the actual page would come from that server, and it would generate the AFT, but on values provided from the hacker!

Comment: Nope. The user could override the on page anti-forgery token, but they would never be able to match what the server would be expecting. The odds of correctly guessing a valid token would be near astronomical. This has been the norm since MVC 1.0. It's perfectly secure and thoroughly tested.

Comment: The user wouldn't have to guess the token, it would be produced by the server.  You would override the data returned by the model for that page, and the server would generate a token based on the data provided in the parameters passed on the URL.  Thus, the token is now valid - even though the data isn't what the programmer expected to have saved to the model.  I.e. http://foo.com?username=bill  will effectively set 'model.username = "bill"', so it will generate the token based on bill, not the expected value.

Comment: That's not how the anti-forgery token works. It has nothing to do with the submitted data.